# How can I change the style of DatePicker?

Tags: android, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to change my datepicker styles, but I don't know the properties.
I'm using the following librarie: https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker

I’ve managed to change the colors, but I would like to change more things, such as the `border radius`.

[image]

I changed the `styles.xml` file this way:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/Dialog.Theme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Dialog.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">#0981bf</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#7a7a7a</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I've searching information about this, but I have not found anything....

Is it possible to change the border radius? Is there information about the items I can change?